# Optimizing without using counters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and would like to hear your thoughts on how to better optimize the code I wrote. It gets the CAGR growth rate of a selection and displays if below the range as well as the mean value next to the range. I know that most code I've seen doesn't use things like counters in for loops, for example. If you guys have any tips I would love to hear them.

```
Function calcCAGR(r As Range) As Double
            ' Declare variables
            Dim c As Range
            Dim firstVal As Long
            Dim lastVal As Long
            Dim I As Integer
            Dim counter As Integer
            I = 0
            counter = 0

            ' Check for null cells and counter range
            For Each c In r
                       I = I + 1
                       If c.Value = 0 Then
                                MsgBox "Null value error"
                                Exit Function
                       End If
            Next c

            ' Set beginning and end values
            For Each c In r
                       counter = counter + 1
                       If counter = 1 Then
                                firstVal = c.Value
                       ElseIf counter = I Then
                                lastVal = c.Value
                                calcCAGR = (((lastVal / firstVal) ^ (1 / I)) - 1)
                       End If
            Next c
End Function

Function checkSpace(s As Range, endPos As Long) As Boolean
            Dim c As Range
            Dim counter As Long

            counter = 0

            For Each c In s

                        ' Increment counter
                        counter = counter + 1

                        'If value is not null than return False
                        If Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(1).Value) Then
                                    checkSpace = False
                                    Exit Function
                        End If

                        ' Check spaces next to last column
                        If counter = endPos Then
                                    If Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(, 1).Value) Then
                                                checkSpace = False
                                                Exit Function
                                    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(1, 1).Value) Then
                                                checkSpace = False
                                                Exit Function
                                    End If
                        End If

            Next c


            ' Return true if passed
            checkSpace = True

End Function

Sub meanCAGR()
            ' Declare variables
            Dim c As Range
            Dim subR As Range
            Dim s As Range
            Dim startPos As Long
            Dim endPos As Long
            Dim counter As Integer
            Dim result As Double
            Dim loc As Worksheet
            Dim total As Double
            Dim rowCountStart As Long
            Dim rowCountLast As Long

            ' Set variables
            Set s = Selection
            Set loc = Sheets("Sheet1")
            endPos = 0
            counter = 0
            total = 0
            'rowCount = Range(s).Rows.Count

            ' Find size of range
            For Each c In s
                        ' Increment counter
                        counter = counter + 1

                        ' If counter is 1 then find the row
                        If counter = 1 Then
                                    startPos = c.Column
                                    rowCountStart = c.Row
                        End If

                        ' Find last row
                        rowCountLast = c.Row

                        ' Get end position
                        endPos = endPos + 1
            Next c

            If rowCountLast - rowCountStart > 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Too many rows in range"
                        Exit Sub
            End If

            If checkSpace(s, endPos) <> True Then
                        MsgBox "Row below range and column spaces next to range must be cleared"
                        Exit Sub
            End If

            counter = 0

            ' Find for each cell in range
            For Each c In s
                        ' Increment endPos
                        counter = counter + 1
                        ' After first cell
                        If counter > 1 Then
                                    ' Set subrange and call calcCAGR
                                    Set subR = loc.Range(loc.Cells(rowCountLast, startPos), loc.Cells(rowCountLast, counter + startPos - 1))
                                    result = calcCAGR(subR)
                                    ' Print CAGR
                                    c.Offset(1).Value = result
                                    total = total + result
                                    c.Offset(1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                        End If
                        If counter = endPos Then
                                    endPos = endPos - 1
                                    c.Offset(, 1).Value = endPos & "-Year Mean"
                                    c.Offset(1, 1).Value = total / endPos
                                    c.Offset(1, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                        End If
            Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: 1st part would suggest posting this on https://superuser.com/ for code review. SO is more for troubleshooting, solutions & bugs, not so much existing code improvement. 2nd part of your question is too broad, but like any language would include error checks.

Comment: @ReturnVoid - I think you meant [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Super User.